# how to check if there is an element in the list without getting out of index error in python

Tags: python

how to check if there is an element in the list without getting out of index error in python?

5. Write a function `add_neighbours` that takes a list of integers and returns a new list, with the same number of elements as the original list but where each integer in the new list is the sum of its neighbours and itself (from the original list)

example, `add_neighbours([1,3,5,7])` returns `[4,9,15,12]` (which is equal to `[1+3, 1+3+5, 3+5+7, 5+7]`)

[image]

Comment: "how to check if there is an element in the list without getting out of index error in python" - the is normally done with `if element in the_list: print("It's in the list!")`

Comment: Welcome to SO!, please read [ask] and update your question accordingly. I would advise attempting the problem and posting the attempt before asking a question. SO is not a homework assistance portal [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to use conditionals to make sure it doesn't get out of the index.
See the commented code below:

```py
def add_neighbours(input_list):
    newlist = []
    for i in range(len(l)):
        # If it's the initial number, sum only with the next item
        if i==0:
            newlist.append(l[i] + l[i+1])
        # If it's the last number, sum only with the previous item
        elif i == len(l)-1:
            newlist.append(l[i] + l[i-1])
        # If it's either the initial or last number, sum with the previous and the next item
        else:
            newlist.append(l[-i] + l[i] + l[i-1])
    return newlist
```

```
print(add_neighbours([1,3,5,7]))
# > [4, 11, 13, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

you should write like this code

```
arr=[1,3,5,7]

newArr=[];


for i in range(len(arr)):
  sum=0;   
  if(i>0):
    sum+=arr[i-1]
  

  sum+=arr[i]

  if(i<(len(arr)-1)):
    sum+=arr[i+1]
  
  newArr.append(sum)
  

print(newArr);
```

Comment: Why there is a semicolon in the print statement? python doesn't need a semicolon you know.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```py
if my_list == []:
```

or do

```py
if len(my_list) == 0:
```

First one check if the list is equal to an empty is list which either returns `True` or `False` if it's `False` then the list is empty. Second one does basically the same but checks if the length of the list is `0` which if it is then the list has no elements in it.